# Advantages of using service in a remote process in Android

Tags: android, service

1. What are the advantages of using remote service over Local Service?
2. If we run service in remote process does this have any special priority when Android kills process due to memory constraints?
3. Does service running in remote process have special capabilities than service running in the same process?
4. If remote process uses more CPU and memory this would be a disadvantage. So in what case/requirement we MUST go to remote process?

Answer (score 0):

Local service can be accessed only with in the application in which it is present.
But Remote service can be used in other applications also.
Remote service is more stable in the sense even if the service is crashed, it would not affect the application.

Comment: I've also noticed that services in remote processes are not usually (but sometimes?) killed when a user swipes away an application in "recent apps."  Background services in the same process seem to always be killed when the user swipes away the application in "recent apps."  Note, I'm taking about processes [specific to an application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), not global processes.